# retain minor versions of packages in apt-mirror

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, apt

OS: Mainly Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.06

Background: Our Chef recipes are pinned with minor version of various packages and libraries(eg: libcouchbase2-core, libcurl3-gnutls, etc).

Problem statement: We have local apt mirror setup, but the problem is that some libraries updates very frequently and which gets synced in our local apt mirror repo. This breaks the Chef deployment as the older version gets removed from the mirror, until we manually go update the recipe with the available version.

Question: I am trying to find a way to retain the older packages for some specific time(say a month) before archiving/deleting. Is there any way? Any help/suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: What software are you using for the mirror?

Comment: I am using apt-mirror to mirror all the Ubuntu official repos like "archive.ubuntu.com", "security-updates", "backports", etc.

Comment: Unless you set autoclean mode, it shouldn't be deleting things I don't think. But it's a very old tool with no docs, so hard to tell.